# Starting a terminal automatically when booting up Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there any way of starting up a terminal on boot up and making it run several commands automatically on Raspberry Pi? The reason I need to do this is to run a Python script that plays audio and displays a bunch of stuff on the console.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Sure, put your command in `/etc/rc.local` and it will run at boot.

Comment: Not a programming question; try http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux ?